# How to free a COM Object with IConnectionPointContainer and IConnectionPoints properly

Tags: c#, com, unmanaged

I have a COM-Object:

```
_myObject = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(...);
```

I can get a IConnectionPointContainer:

```
_cpc = (IConnectionPointContainer)_myObject;
```

And get my IConnectionPoint out of this:

```
IConnectionPoint _cp;
_cpc.FindConnectionPoint(typeof(IMyCPInterface).GUID, out _cp);
_cp.Advise(this, out _cookie);
```

I am not sure about the correct way to free all the resources now. **How do I release all the created resources properly?**

At the moment I do it like below, but I am not sure if I'm release everything properly:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool pDisposing)
{
  if(!_isDisposed)
  {
    if(pDisposing)
    {
      //dispose managed
    }

    if(_cookie > 0 && _cp != null)
    {
      _cp.Unadvise(_cookie);
      _cp = null;            //<-- ReleaseComObject(_cp); ?
      _cookie = 0;
    }

    //I don't release _cpc, because it is the same object as _myObject?

    if(_myObject != null)
    {
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_myObject);
      _myObject = null;
    }

    _isDisposed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: In general: Release as many times the ref count is increased. I.e.: when querying an interface (by casting like: ((IConnectionPointContainer)_myObject), you should read the doc's to determine if the ref-count is increased (it usually is). The Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, _cp must be released. _cpc must also be released and of course _myObject must be released as well, maybe twice due to the IMyInterface cast.

Comment: You can always test it, the ref-count must be 0 when you are done with the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the comments: this should result in a proper disposure of the COM object:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool pDisposing)
{
    if(!_isDisposed)
    {
        if(pDisposing) //dispose managed
        {
            if(_cookie > 0 && _cp != null)
            {
                _cp.Unadvise(_cookie);
                _cookie = 0;
            }
            if (_cp != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_cp);
                _cp = null;    
            }
            if(_cpc != null)
            {
                //needed due to the implicit queryinterface on cast 
                //_cpc = (IConnectionPointContainer)_myObject;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_cpc);
                _cpc = null;
            }
            if(_myObject != null)
            {
                //you could test if Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_myObject) == 0
                //If it's not, the IMyInterface cast is probably increasing the refcount.
                //but use FinalRelease just to be safe.
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_myObject);
                _myObject = null;
            }
        }
        _isDisposed = true;
     }
 }
```

`_cpc.FindConnectionPoint(typeof(IMyCPInterface).GUID, out _cp);` will increment the ref-count:

> If the call is successful, the caller is responsible for releasing the connection point by calling Release when the connection point is no longer needed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The FinalReleaseComObject method:

> The FinalReleaseComObject method releases the managed reference to a COM object. Calling this method is equivalent to calling the ReleaseComObject method in a loop until it returns 0 (zero).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

An additional note:

Although querying interfaces on an object might result in returning the same object, sometimes even the same pointer value, a call to `ReleaseComObject` is still legitimate. This is because of the internal ref-count which can trigger a cleanup of the object if it hits 0.

More info about managed RCW and COM:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: None of this is required.  The use of `ReleaseComObject` should **only** be used in cases where you can't wait for a garbage collection to finalize the RCW, and `FinalReleaseComObject` should **only** be used when you're sure you want to detach every RCW from the underlying COM object.

Comment: @PauloMadeira: good point there. I'll loosen-up the term. Although I think its good habit to release the COM objects, especially when they are instantiated very often.

Comment: It depends on whether the object releasing the COM object (from the managed point of view) is the sole owner of it.  Usually, objects that are instantiated very often fall in this case, but not necessarily.  E.g. if you're iterating Excel sheets or cells, if you're not sure that managed code may keep a reference to one of them, you should't use `*ReleaseComObject`, instead you must rely on (possibly forced, periodically or on demand) garbage collection.

Comment: When I close the application (`Dispose(false);` called by finalizer) it crashes at Unadvise with `InvalidComObjectException`. In this case the CRW (or CCW?) was released earlier than my object, right? So the unadvise should be moved to the `if(pDisposing)` block? I mean I tried it and it works but I am not sure again if this should be done...

Comment: That's correct, disposal of managed objects should be inside the `if (disposing)` block, and an RCW is a managed object.  When it gets GCed (and thus your object too, since it pointed to the RCW), there's no way to guarantee it finalizes before or after your object.

Comment: Hmm, the comments make more sense than my answer :|

Comment: I checked the ref-counts. Code above is giving me a ref-count of -1 after releasing `_myObject`. (Note: It seems that all of them pointing to the same ref-count, same RCW?) Since [IConnectionPoint.Unadvise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is calling a Release, I think the ReleaseComObject call of _cp is not required. Commenting this out, the ref-counter goes to 0 after _myObject-ReleaseComObject. Can I do this?

Comment: @fedab: most important thing is that, if you are releasing the objects youself, the ref-count must hit 0 if you're done with it. -1 is once to often. I wasn't able to pinpoint the location where the ref-counts wouldn't add up.